# iOS Memory Leak with Activity View

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I just discovered a memory leak in my app but I'm not really sure how to go about fixing it.  It involves an activity view which is used to share the url of the current article being viewed from an rss feed. I'm not really sure why the leak is happening.  Any ideas or advice?[image: iPhone Leak] 
[image: iPad Leak]

The method in question for the iPhone version is:

```
- (void) showMenu
{   
    NSURL *urlToShare = hackyURL;
    NSArray *activityItems = @[urlToShare];
    TUSafariActivity *activity = [[TUSafariActivity alloc] init];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:@[activity]];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT: I've fixed the iPhone leak by changing the above code to this:**

```
__block UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:@[activity]];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = nil; activityVC = nil;}];
```

The iPad version is essentially the same except that it uses a popover to display the activity view.

```
- (void)showMenu
{    
    NSURL *urlToShare = hackyURL;
    NSArray *activityItems = @[urlToShare];
    TUSafariActivity *activity = [[TUSafariActivity alloc] init];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:@[activity]];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    if ([popover isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        popover = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
        [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:systemAction permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: if you found an answer to your own question, please add the solution as a proper answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the iPhone leak by changing the above code to this:

```
__block UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:@[activity]];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = nil; activityVC = nil;}];
```

but I can't figure out how to fix the leak for the popover on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ([self.popover isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popover = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
        [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:systemAction permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: That did not fix the leak.